# Countdown timer from a start date and time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

Hi all I have the following countdown timer in JS - that I use across pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         var count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 60
         countdown = setInterval(function() {
             localStorage.setItem('count'), count);
             $("span.countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds + " Remaining");

             if (count == 0) {
                   clearInterval(countdown);
                   localStorage.removeItem('count');
             }
             count--;
         }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Im finding that if the user makes many PHP post requests on my page the timer doesn't really countdown.

I was wondering whether it is possible to store a date time in localstorage and then when the user reloads the page - calculate the difference between the time in local storage and the time now - many apologies for the lack of code I am a complete JS noob

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, set a session variable, `$_SESSION['EndTime']`. As each page loads, compare the current time with session variable and output the remaining time.

Comment: and then pass the remaining time to the countdown fuunction?

Comment: Output the value to the page so that JS can use it. I'm assuming that you want to dynamically show a countdown clock between page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Date object to get the current time: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Examples:

```
new Date().getTime() // gets the amount of alle milliseconds since 1970 => also usefull for the serialization

new Date(milliseconds) // restoring the date object
```

I hope, that helps you